# How to extend both FragmentActivity and WearableActivity in one activity?

Tags: android-fragmentactivity, wear-os

How to extend both `FragmentActivity` and `WearableActivity` in one activity?

I have a watch app that I want to do always-on ambient mode, but it is a `fragmentActivity`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With friends' help, just not use v4 support library for fragments. Use import android.app.Fragment; instead of import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

Comment: With a FragmentPagerAdapter (in need of getSupportFragmentManager(), you need something else than WearableActivity. How would you solve that?

Comment: Class android.app.Fragment is deprecated as of API level 28, see https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment

Answer (score 2):

You should implement the `AmbientMode.AmbientCallbackProvider` instead of using `WearableActivity`.

It is the preferred method and it still gives you the `onEnterAmbient()`, `onAmbientUpdate()`, and `onExitAmbient()` but you can use `FragmentActivity`.

[Official docs call out the details (and example code)](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/always-on.html).

Comment: `AmbientMode.AmbientCallbackProvider` is now deprecated. You should use `AmbientModeSupport.AmbientCallbackProvider` instead.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/always-on):

> The 27.1.0 version of the Android Support Library enables a new way to support ambient mode that uses the **AmbientModeSupport** class rather than the **WearableActivity** class. You can decide whether you want to use the new, preferred way to support ambient mode or instead extend the WearableActivity class.

Therefore, to use the new `androidx.fragment.app.Fragment` and `FragmentManager`, you must use the new [AmbientModeSupport](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/wear/ambient/AmbientModeSupport.html) class. Otherwise, you can continue using `WearableActivity`.